# $_GET["id"] don't respond

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php , and i want make a test with GET .
I want display , for example "ok" on my php page if my id parameter is 1 but i have always 1 when i change the id parameter to another value .

### Details :

when i make this url :

http://localhost:81/test/testajax.php?id=2

### expected result :

not ok

### obtained result :

ok

### testajax.php

```
    <?php

    if($_GET["id"] = 1)
    {
    die('ok');
    }
    else 
    {
    die('not ok');
    }

?>
```

Comment: use  if($_GET["id"] == 1) for compair string

Comment: $_GET["id"] = 1 means you are assign 1 to $_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One equal sign (=) sets the value of a variable. `$foo = "bar";` would set `$foo` to store **bar**.

You want to use two equal signs (==), which is a comparison operator. `($foo == "bar")` would check to see if `$foo` is equal to **bar**.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the different types of operators at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php
May be you should go through this basics before you start.

Answer (score 0):

you should put two equal signs to compare.

```
if($_GET["id"]==1)
```

correct code:

```
<?php

if($_GET["id"] == 1)
{
die('ok');
}
else 
{
die('not ok');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting the variable, the if statement is always equating to true

Just thought it was worth Noting this as that is the logical reason for your issue